# Python: how can I count the occurrences in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, find-occurrences

I have a `list` of `tuples`, with each tuple having two elements: an integer and an inner list. The list of tuples has `len=900` and each inner list can have `len=2`, `len=3`, or `len=4` depending on the case being.

This is an excerpt of the list:

`mylist=[(0, [1.0, 1.0]), (1, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), ..., (31, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), ...]`.

This is a specific case in which each element of the inner lists is `1.0`, but I want to deal with the generic case featuring different values.

**My questions:**

1) How can I count the total number of elements within the inner lists? In the visualized example this number would be `2+3+4=9`.

2) How can I count the occurrences of each value (or, better, of each *bin*) within the inner lists?

Comment: Show us your code – what you've tried already.

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I don't know where to begin from... Apologies.

Comment: I see you've gotten your answer, but SO is not intended to be a coding service. You should at least attempt a solution on your own and show what you have tried before coming here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of elements:

```
sum(len(l) for _, l in mylist)
```

Number of occurrences:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(x for _, l in mylist for x in l)
```

Occurrences binned:

```
from collections import Counter
binsize = 100
Counter(x - x % binsize for _, l in mylist for x in l)
```

Comment: What if I had a much higher spread in my values, so that I'd need to use bins? How could I select the width of my bins to tell `Counter` what the ranges would be? You see what I mean?

Comment: No need to create intermediate list object in both cases: `sum(len(l) for _, l in mylist)` and `Counter(x for _, l in mylist for x in l)` is enough

Comment: @massiou Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 3):

You just iterate through the list then iterate through the inner list and you create a dictionnary to count each value separately.
Also you increment for each innerlist a variable to count the elements.

```
inner_list_count = 0
value_count = dict()
for key,innerlist in mylist:
    inner_list_count += len(innerlist)
    for value in innerlist:
        if value not in value_count:
            value_count(value) = 0
        value_count(value) += 1
```

Comment: Maybe you just wanted guidance and not a code? In that case sorry I misunderstood

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to get you started.  For #1, you can get the lengths of each part of the tuples with a list comprehension:

`lens = [len(y) for x, y in mylist]`

This will generate an array of the lengths of each sublist in the tuples, so `lens[0]` will equal 2, etc.